# Model on NetLogo: Color Fractions

Tags: computer-science, computability, computational-mathematics

I have the following code in NetLogo:

patches-own [ column-number ]

to setup
clear-all
ask patches
[ set plabel-color black
set column-number pxcor + max-pxcor ]
go
reset-ticks
end

to go
let n numerator
;; go through every patch one at a time in order,
;; (left to right, top to bottom)
foreach sort patches [ p ->
ask p [
ifelse column-number >= width [
;; patches outside the given width are black
set plabel ""
set pcolor black
] [
;; other patches get a color and label
;; perform the division
set plabel floor (n / denominator)
ifelse plabel = 0
[ set pcolor gray + 1.5 ]          ;; 0 is gray
[ set pcolor plabel * 10 + 6 ]     ;; other digits get colors
;; compute the new numerator
set n 10 * remainder n denominator
]
]
]
;; put a decimal point after the number in the
;; upper left corner patch
ask patch min-pxcor max-pycor
[ set plabel word plabel "." ]
display
end

And I want to modify this code. The aim is to see $\pi$ and square roots in the programme.

Can anyone give an idea to modify this programme?

I have done some modifications like change the lightness/darkness of the boxes and change the colour of the boxes depending of the number is odd or pair.

Thanks so much.